# Makefile: compiling several unit test *.out files into a single test executable (C++)

Tags: makefile

Please forgive me if this is a repeat question. I am fairly new to writing Makefiles, and so I was not really sure how to find what I am looking for.

I am getting acquainted with Boost.Test and am writing unit tests on a file-per-file basis.

This is my directory structure:

```
- cpp
    - sim
        - Makefile
        - bin
        - src
            - ExampleClass.cpp
    - tests
        - Makefile
        - bin
        - src
            -ExampleClass_T.cpp
```

Essentially, I would like to write individual *.cpp test case files using Boost, as displayed above.

Here is the content of my tests/Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -g -v -Wall -I$(ODIR_TEST) -I$(SDIR_TEST) \
-I$(SDIR) -I$(ODIR) -I$(BOOST_ROOT)
ODIR_TEST = ./bin
SDIR_TEST = ./src
ODIR = ../sim/bin
SDIR = ../sim/src

%.out : $(SDIR_TEST)/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $< $@
```

executing `make` generates a **No targets. Stop.** error message. Any ideas as to why make thinks there is no target? Wouldn't %.out act as the target here, or can a wildcard not act in that manner?

I recognize that in the Makefile above, I am attempting to generate a *.out file for each *.cpp file; in addition, I would like to generate a final executable that is a culmination of all generated *.out files. Is this possible, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Any other advice or Makefile best practices, especially with regards to test automation, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The "build path" is `.cpp (source) -> .o (object file) -> a.out (executable)`.  So yes, you can build a separate executable for every .cpp (provided each .cpp has a `main()` function).  And yes, you can compile all your *.cpp files into one executable: provided only *ONE* .cpp has a `main()` function.  But no, you cannot merge multiple a.out into a single .exe.

Comment: You get that message because your makefile doesn't list any target.  You have created a pattern rule that tells make, "if you are asked build a target that matches the pattern `%.out`, here's how you can do it".  But you haven't asked it to build anything.  A pattern rule is just a method for doing something.  It's like a function... it doesn't do anything by itself.  You have to actually call the function if you want it to do something.  Here, you could say `make foo.out`.  Or you can create a target like `all` that lists your `.out` files as prerequisites.

Comment: @MadScientist that makes sense. As I would like to stay on the side of generalizing rather than hardcoding, I am thinking I could define a variable, such as ```TARGETS```, that uses ```wildcard``` to match all ```.out``` files in a particular directory, and then I could create an ```all``` target that lists ```TARGETS``` as a prerequisite. To make this happen, however, I would want to dictate the path of where I want my ```.out``` files to end up. What changes would I have to make to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, you can't use `wildcard` to match all `.out` files, because when you invoke `make` before any targets are created there won't be any `.out` files existing for `wildcard` to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seemed to have found a workaround, though it can likely be optimized.

```
PROG = main
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -g -Wall -I$(ODIR_TEST) -I$(SDIR_TEST) \
-I$(SDIR) -I$(ODIR) -I$(BOOST_ROOT)
ODIR_TEST = ./bin
SDIR_TEST = ./src
OUTDIR = ./execs
ODIR = ../sim/bin
SDIR = ../sim/src
TEST_EXEC_NAMES = $(notdir $(basename $(wildcard $(SDIR_TEST)/*.cpp)))

# default rule (main.cpp)
$(OUTDIR)/$(PROG) : $(SDIR_TEST)/main.cpp $(TEST_EXEC_NAMES)
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

% : $(SDIR_TEST)/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(OUTDIR)/$@ $<
```

I specify a default target in my first rule. I include `$(TEST_EXEC_NAMES)` as a prereq to make sure that all of my individual test executables are built using the pattern rule.

Specifying my executable filenames from their .cpp counterparts is done with a series of function calls (wildcard, basename, and notdir).

Again, this is surely not the fastest way I could accomplish my task, but it has gotten me onto compilation errors.